# Remote connection to a Windows 2008 Server Web edition

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, remote-desktop, remote-desktop-services

I have just installed Windows 2008 web server to have a development/test site on my office.

In the test network I only have 2 machines:

- Windows server 2008 Web Edition
- Vista x64 client machine with Visual Studio

The client and the server are networked using a NETGEAR router.

I have enabled Remote desktop on the server and when I try to connect to it within the Vista client I get the credential window as in the following screenshot.

[image]

But even if I write the correct credentials I am not able to remote login on the server.

Where am I doing wrong?

**Update 1**

I have even tried to create a folder share on the server. But I am not able to access it for the same reason. User or password invalid it says. But this is impossible as I am logging in the server with the same credentials.

[image]

**Update 2**

If I try to browse the network from the RDP client I receive a message saying that there are no server running Terminal Services in my network.... :O
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked the firewall (and file sharing) settings on the Windows 2008 Server?

Comment: I have completely disabled the firewall.

Comment: A possible way to check for a credentials issue may be to issue a "dir \\127.0.0.1\c$ /user:VIMBooNET\administrator" command on the server itself. "VIMBOONET\administrator" is based off of your screen-shot.

Comment: Got a message: Invalid switch "/user"

Comment: This is on the Windows 2008 Web Server?

Comment: Yes. I have executed the command on the server.

Comment: Oops... Microsoft changed things ever so slightly again... Try "net use \\127.0.0.1\ipc$ /user:VIMBooNET\administrator" instead. You also might try enabling the Windows Firewall service, then turning it off from the Control Panel settings (if you wish to have it off) - if you have not already as it also seems like it can take on weird default states after the initial installation of Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending the wrong credentials OR using an outdated RDB client. Try running windows update. I am not sure that Vista already supports the new security features that 2008 R2 brings in as default settings. I know most open source / alternative / linux rdp clients have a problem there.

Additionally, prefix with domain or machine name (plus ). If your machine is in a domain sometimes things go wrong there (and it tries your domain name, which obviously will not work).

What error do you get? You are so nice to show us what you enter (although we do not speak italian here - thanks), but you dont say anything about the errors.

Does it just time out? Check firewall. It is a simple TCP connect, but still. Also the ports must be open on the other side (the server).

Do you get a password / secureity error? What is it?

Comment: I just installed the machine yesterday. before configuring in this pseudo network I have done all the necessary updates. The machine is not in a domain as I just wan to use it as it would be on internet facing. I am using the `hostname\administrator` to connect. I have completely disabled the firewall. There-s no error except what you can see on the screenshot that can be translated with "Connection attempt failed"; It says that my username or password are invalid but this is not true because I can login on the server desktop regularly...

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Remote Desktop enabled on the server?  Right-click on the Computer icon > Properties > Remote Settings.  It should automatically add an exclusion to the firewall if my memory serves me correctly.

You can test that it's working by going to the command prompt and typing `netstat -aon | find ":3389"` which will return something like this:
`TCP    0.0.0.0:3389           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       1716`

You can also test that the firewall is open from another machine by `telnet <hostname or IP> 3389` and you should get a blank cursor blinking (you can exit by hitting CTRL-] and then typing quit).

Comment: @gravyface: Yes it is enabled even because otherwise I would'nt get a login window, is'nt it? Anyway I have checked just now. The firewall is disabled for every network profile.

Comment: @gravyface: Yes I have Remote desktop enabled from the Remote Settings options but the server is not running the Terminal Server Role as it is a Web Edition and does not have that role. How I can do?

Comment: Newer versions of the RDP client will ask for the credentials before it establishes a connection.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the newer version of RDP client. I did not know. I have tried the netstat command and i get two rows. First one is like your sample but with 1116 port number. the second one is `TCP [::]:3389 [::]:0 LISTENING 1116`

Comment: 1116 is the process ID; yours looks correct.

Comment: I have tried to telnet the server and I can get the blinking cursor. I have also tried what described in this support article `http://support.microsoft.com/kb/934430/en-us?fr=1` but I am getting the same results